# Device Android API

Tags: android

So my device Lenovo is runnig Android Kit kat 4.4.2 API 19 and i want to debug an aplication from Android Studio with target API 22, my goal is to use Material Design, whetever when i run the aplication give me an eror.
When y set the theme android:Theme.Material, it tell me that it requires minSdkTarget API 21, i set minSdkTarget = 19, when i set it to 21 and run it give's me the error 
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.andrei.desingpattern
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Should my device have API 21 instaled ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a emulator. Or an older version of your library

Answer (score 0):

Devices are not guaranteed to receive Android updates forever. It is inevitable at some point that your device will no longer get the latest operating system.

I cannot speak to your specific device, but the answer to your problem is that you should be using the AppCompat library to bring Material to older devices.

As you have noticed, `Theme.Material` is unavailable if your device is running anything older than API level 21 (Lollipop). AppCompat offers `Theme.AppCompat`, which emulates a lot of what `Theme.Material` does, but in a way that works with older devices as well.

Google has an excellent article on bringing Material to devices running pre-Lollipop versions of Android [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

In general, you should keep `minSdkVersion` to the lowest API version you want to support, keeping in mind that many users will not have the latest version on their phones.